# How to combine Flask web application and Windows Forms App (C#) into one .EXE file/application?

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, flask, exe

I did this project where I have Flask website and also this Windows Forms App view of the Flask app. My final goal is to make one .exe application that runs the two scripts, first the app.py and then the C# code for the view.
I did .exe file of the python code with pyinstaller. Everything is running perfectly when I run the python .exe file and then run the C# code with Visual Studio.
My question is how can I make .exe file that runs both scripts when I click on the icon, so I can send one application to my friends, not two separate.

Comment: Do you want one process to start the other? or do you want to run .Net and Python in the same process? I'm not sure the later is possible in any simple way.

Comment: I want them in the same process